# Passing MULTIPLE values from vlookup in macro

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, excel-2010

I have created a Name in Excel called 'DisplayColumnsRows' which refers to =Sheet1!$C$6:$E$36

```
Column C = list of worksheet names (e.g Control)
Column D = list of columns or range to display (e.g A,B,C:H)
Column E = list of rows or range to display (e.g 1,2,5:10)
```

I have created a macro to look at each row in the name 'DisplayColumnsRows' and where Column C displays a worksheet name (Is not blank), i would like it to hide all columns and rows from that worksheet and then unhide/display the specific columns from Column D and the rows from Column E.

So far i have created the following code, but am stuck on how to pass the values into ws.Range to display the columns and rows.

```
Sub Run_Me_To_Fix_Columns()
   Dim ws As Worksheet

'List the names of the worksheets to exclude from Sub resizingColumns

    Const excludeSheets As Variant = "Control/DIVA_Report/Asset_Details"

'Perform the following for each worksheet not excluded
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, Split(excludeSheets, "/"), 0)) Then
        Call displayColumnRow(ws)
        End If

    Next
End Sub


Sub displayColumnRow(ws As Worksheet)

    Dim DisplayColumns       As Variant
    Dim DisplayRows          As Variant
    Dim myrange

    Set myrange = Worksheets("Control").Range("range_hideColumnRow")

    'Hide All Columns and Rows
    ws.Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ws.Columns.EntireRow.Hidden = True

    'Lookup Worksheet name and identify columns & rows to display
    DisplayColumns = Application.VLookup(ws.Name, myrange, 2, False)
    DisplayRows = Application.VLookup(ws.Name, myrange, 3, False)

    'Display Columns and Rows (Unhide)
    If Not IsError(DisplayColumns) Then
    ws.Range("DisplayColumns").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    'MsgBox DisplayColumns
    End If

    If Not IsError(DisplayRows) Then
    ws.Range("DisplayRows").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    'MsgBox DisplayRows
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The best way to get help here is to first try something. If you get stuck, do some research, make an attempt at fixing things yourself, and only then ask a specific question about your attempts, showing what you have tried. Questions asking for complete solutions without demonstrating research effort usually get downvoted and closed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I have had a go as best as i can, therefore i would be very grateful for any help.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change how you enter the rows and columns you want to show--always enter the columns or rows as ranges, even if it is a single column. For example, instead of `A,B,C:H` do this: `A:A,B:B,C:H`.